# How do I make a JavaScript whitelist to prevent XSS?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xss

I only have a few jQuery scripts running on my practice site that handle UI dynamics. What I also do is store the HTML from a web page into a database and "echo" that HTML on the client side.  I was wondering, then, could I make a whitelist of only the JavaScript that I want to run?

Comment: You want to scrape 3rd party sites, store the results, then display it later?

Comment: technically not a 3rd party site, Its my website I made to practice computer security, and I've been toying with using html purifier or a whitelist. A whitelist seems like an efficient, simpler solution

Comment: Having worked on a CMS, my first question is why do you need to store the html? Are the people entering the html admins? I have a feeling you're going to go down a rabbit hole trying to allow only specific JavaScript methods from running. If only admins have access the question becomes what does it buy you to have a JavaScript whitelist if a compromised account could potentially cause worse problems?

Comment: purifying javascript will never be a reliable operation. You'll always be cleaning up the next mess. Consider how many ways an infinite loop can be created, and trying to scan code for each and everyone of them.

Comment: well I honestly only wanted to know how to make a javascript whitelist, sorry this is just for practice, I should clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PHP

First you should always filter your data using for example filter extension(I would use this). These slides could help you learn filter => http://derickrethans.nl/talks/filter-quebec7.pdf

Javascript

Next you could use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of .html() to prevent xss.